# Why is git suddenly asking me to tell it who I am?

Tags: git, passwords, config

I've been using `git` with no issues for a few weeks. I logged into it for the first time weeks ago and never had to do so since. But this time, when I'm trying to make a commit, I get this message:

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'IMRAY@IMRAY-HP.(none)')
```

Why is this happening now? Might this be something malicious?

Comment: Did your network configuration change - including DNS?  It looks like git has previously been able to autodetect your email address, but the (none) part looks like this doesn't work any more.

Comment: Not that I can think of. Nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

There is a global configuration file for git (gitconfig) which contains user-email and username details.

It could be possible that this file has been updated and now these details are not available in this configuration file which is causing this error.

Please verify this file for these details.

In case these details are not there, you can set your git details in this file by executing the mentioned commands.